# Firebird .NET Provider 5.0.0 and EF6

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird

I have been trying to create Entity Data Model of Firebird database, but i can't get past this error:

[image: this error.]

I have installed:

- DDEX provider 3.0.2.0
- Firebird .NET Provider 5.0.0.0 (tried both installing it with .msi from Firebird's official site and  manually adding refrence to
  project and installing it from NuGet)
- EntityFramework.Firebird(from NuGet)

Here is my machine.config:

```
    <system.data>
         <DbProviderFactories>
            <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
         </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

and here is my App.config:

```
 <configSections>
     <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
 </configSections>

 <system.data>
     <DbProviderFactories>
         <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
         <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
     </DbProviderFactories>
 </system.data>

 <entityFramework>
     <providers>
         <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
     </providers>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
 </entityFramework>
```

Here is my connection string:

```
metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string=&quot;character set=NONE;initial catalog=C:\Users\brakm\Desktop\test.fdb;user id=sysdba;password=masterkey;data source=localhost&quot;
```

More info:

- Visual Studio 2015
- Firebird version is 2.5
- Tried using EF 6.0 and EF 6.13

**EDIT**

I've tried creating model in new(clean) project (C# Console application) and it worked. i installed EntityFramework.Firebird(from NuGet) and it automatically installed base EF and Firebird sql provider, but after doing the same with original project nothing changed, i tried cleaning project from anything related with firebird including removing references, clearing packages.config and manually deleting any firebird related file from project.

Comment: also post your connection string

Comment: edited in connection string

Comment: inside VS, click on server manager and try to create a connection to the FB datbase. I think this fails and you can't see FB here. Correct? After a VSIX extension gets updated, DDEX provider is lost (http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-581). Repair DDEX and now try again.

Comment: Well, i don't have any problems adding fb connection i can see it without any problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to fix it,

- Remove all Entity framework and Firebird references from project
- Clear packages.config file
- Delete all files that are linked to EF and Firebird from project directory
- Download EntityFramework.Firebird from NuGet (this will automatically install FirebirdClient and EntityFramework oldest compatible version by default)
- Update EF to latest versions since base 6.0 caused crashes for unknown(to me) reason

Comment: nice to hear that you fixed it :)   +1

Comment: This worked for me as well, there is also a newer version of the FBCLient that shows up in the upgrade tab but I DID NOT upgrade that piece.